# Using the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

Question: A typical coin is tossed 9000 times. What is the probability that the number of heads is 4800 and 5000?

I will be using the Central Limit Theorem to be solving this problem. I am unsure of what my standard deviation would be in this case. In order to find the N(u, standard deviation/n), I would need to find the standard deviation. I am not particularly sure what my expected value for the number of heads would be.

Answer (score 0):

The number of heads is a sum of independent, identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with parameter $1/2$. (If you haven't heard the term "Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p$", it means that the variables are equal to $1$ with probability $p$ and equal to $0$ with probability $1-p$.) The mean of the sum is the sum of the means (this always happens) and the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances (this uses the independence). Do you know how to find the mean and variance for a variable with the Bernoulli(1/2) distribution? Call them $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ respectively. Then you want to use a normal approximation with mean $9000 \mu$ and variance $9000 \sigma^2$.

Comment: Yes, I do! u=9000(0.5), variance=9000(0.5)(0.5)! I thought that was how I should have done it, but was not sure! However, would I be using the Central Limit Theorem for this question?

Comment: @user3472296 You actually want 9000 according to your problem statement, but yes, that's essentially right. Now set up a normal approximation with those parameters.

Comment: So I would be using the Central Limit Theorem? If not, can you explain why?

Comment: @user3472296 You can use the Central Limit Theorem to (rather accurately) approximate the probability of interest. An exact answer would use the binomial distribution instead, but that is probably not what your exercise is asking for.

Comment: My exercise does not note to use the Central Limit Theorem, but I did feel the Central Limit Theorem would be more accurate.

Comment: @user3472296 Technically it is an approximation (you are not considering a limit of many samples, you are just considering a large number of samples), but adding up the ~200 terms required to get the probability of being between 4800 and 5000 seems much harder for a very slight increase in accuracy.

Comment: Are you sure you have the numbers correct? if so, the average number of heads is 4500 and there is almost no chance there will be more than 4650 heads, which is (roughly) three standard deviations above the mean. So that means the interval between 4800 and 5000 is going to be waaay out in "essentially zero probability territory." If you try to use the normal approximation to the binomial, you won't find the resulting numbers in a normal probability table. They'll be way beyond the range of the table. Maybe it's a sort of trick problem to illustrate that can happen..Will check in a.m. for resp.

Comment: Bruce Trumbo has a point, the range you are looking at is about 6 standard deviations above the mean. So it's possible this was sort of a trick question where the correct answer was "essentially zero".

Comment: Using Matlab's normcdf function I find the answer is about $1.2 \cdot 10^{-10}$, which is (to floating point precision) the same as the probability of just being greater than 4800.